# MATLAB: Undefined function 'rotm2tform' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I get an error when running the following command in MATLAB R2019a

```
clc
clear
rotm = [1 0 0 ; 0 -1 0; 0 0 -1];
tform = rotm2tform(rotm)
```

Command Window:

```
Undefined function 'rotm2tform' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ex2_1 (line 4)
tform = rotm2tform(rotm)
```

The example is taken from https://se.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rotm2tform.html

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the Robotics System Toolbox installed? Typing `ver` at the command prompt will show you which toolboxes are installed.

Comment: I did not. I have it now and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As beaker pointed out, **Robotics System Toolbox** needs to be installed. This was the problem in my case. Now the example works fine.